# Connection pooled in C# (Apache.NMS)

Tags: c#, .net, nms

I am researching how to use a connection pool in C#.Net (we are using Apache.NMS). So far the documentation I found, e.g.:

- http://activemq.apache.org/spring-support.html
  and
- http://activemq.apache.org/maven/activemq-core/apidocs/org/apache/activemq/pool/PooledConnectionFactory.html

Does not very much relate to .net development.

In .Net we are only given `NMSConnectionFactory` class with `CreateConnection()` method which doesn't seem to implement a pool of connection.

The reason I wanted to figure this out is that I don't want to create a connection each time the message is being sent.

How do I use/configure connection pool in C# for activeMQ?

Comment: Choosing between a pool of connections or creating a connection every time you send a message is a logical ["false dilemma"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_dilemma). These are not the only two choices available to you. In the absence of a connection pool you can simply cache and re-use an existing connection rather than blindly creating and closing one every time you need to send a message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The C# client doesn't currently provide a pooled version of the Connection factory like what the Java client provides.  You could of course implement one and donate it to the project.

Comment: Hm.. not quite the answer I was looking for, but thanks anyways ;)